# Why not resize pictures? Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to implement this simple example

[link](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_images.asp)

I add to my image,class `img-responsive`

This is **my code:**

```
<div class="image">
   <img width="500" height="330" src="http://dgprint.dg-site.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/image-500x330.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="image">                          
</div>
```

Watch this example simply not resize the image ... although I did like the example.

Something is wrong with my website ... I think. Bootrstrap is loaded.

[link my site](http://dgprint.dg-site.com/)

For example,if I add to logo class `img-rounded` works,which means that the bootstrap function is loaded.

```
<div class="left">
    <a href="http://dgprint.dg-site.com/">
    <img class="img-rounded" src="http://web.eela.ro/dgprint/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/LOGO.png">        </a>
</div>
```

I do not understand why not resize images.
You tell me please where I wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I just checked your link. Which images are not working?

Comment: You are applying inline width to image.

Change to 

`<img  src="http://dgprint.dg-site.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/image-500x330.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="image"> `

Answer (score 1):

You have this part

```
.container {
      width: 1080px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      position: relative;
}
```

You need to change it to 100% with media query. Find some break point and inspect your css with inpect element in Chrome or Firebug. It's just css with fix widths.

Answer (score 1):

This will solve your issue-

You have set your CSS as -

```
.container {
  width: 1080px;
}
```

Modifiy it to -

```
.container {
  max-width: 1080px;
}
```

Change this in every `container` class. This will also resize your images

**EDIT:**

Your website isn't Bootstrap ready. You have used wrong classes everywhere. 
Tips :

- One `container` class is enough for the whole website.
- All the `row` must be nested under `container`
- All `columns` must compulsorily be a child of `row`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have all the calls to boostrap?

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

OR downloaded the DIST

```
bootstrap/
├── css/
│   ├── bootstrap.css
│   ├── bootstrap.css.map
│   ├── bootstrap.min.css
│   ├── bootstrap-theme.css
│   ├── bootstrap-theme.css.map
│   └── bootstrap-theme.min.css
├── js/
│   ├── bootstrap.js
│   └── bootstrap.min.js
└── fonts/
    ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
    ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
    ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
    ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
    └── glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen your website http://dgprint.dg-site.com/ 
You have not added img-responsive class yet. 
Also I saw you have not incorporated colum level structure that bootstrap provides.

have this kind of structure (I have taken this code from your website
)

```
<div class="container">
                        <div class="row">   <div class="the-content col-md-6">
                                <h1 class="title">
                                    <a href="http://dgprint.dg-site.com/?p=15" title="OUR EXPERIENCE">
                                        OUR EXPERIENCE                                  </a>
                                </h1>
                                <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>

                                                            </div><!-- the-content -->
                            <div class="image col-md-6">
                                <img height="330" src="http://dgprint.dg-site.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/image-500x330.jpg" class="attachment-home-post wp-post-image img-responsive" alt="image">                          </div>
                        </div></div>
```